# How to change menu item text?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I need to change menu item text on runtime. I've try to use GetMenuItemInfo() and SetMenuItemInfo():

```
case WM_NOTIFYICONMSG:
    switch (lParam)  {
    case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        someAction();
        break;
    case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        POINT point;
        GetCursorPos(&point);

        HMENU hMenu;
        HMENU hMenuTrackPopup;

        hMenu = LoadMenu(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU));
        if (hMenu) {
            MENUITEMINFOA menuitem = { sizeof(MENUITEMINFOA) };
            GetMenuItemInfoA(hMenu, IDM_EXIT, false, &menuitem);
            menuitem.dwTypeData = "New text here";
            SetMenuItemInfoA(hMenu, IDM_EXIT, false, &menuitem);
            hMenuTrackPopup = GetSubMenu(hMenu, 0);
            TrackPopupMenu(hMenuTrackPopup, 0, point.x, point.y, 0, hWnd, NULL);
            DestroyMenu(hMenu);
        }
    }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    break;
```

But it doesn't work, text doesn't changed. What I am doing wrong? How to implement it?

Comment: *If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero. If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, use the GetLastError function.* - Check for errors. Also note that pointing a `const char *` to a string literal was deprecated before C++11 and is currently illegal. The documentation also makes no promises of not modifying that data.

Comment: Thank you for comment. But SetMenuItemInfoA() returns 1. As I see, this mean the function succeeds. About pointing char: how to set it correctly?

Comment: Set it something that can actually be modified rather than constant data. And checking `SetMenuItemInfo` isn't enough. Check the others as well.

Comment: I've checked GetLastError(). It returns 2. As I know that is mean ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. But what is the file needed here?

Comment: It's probably garbage because the documentation says that `GetLastError` is valid if the function fails, not succeeds. I meant to make sure all of the winapi functions succeed.

Comment: So, it looks ok, but doesn't works. What's wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: You are not using MENUITEMDATA correctly, you forgot to set the fMask member.  Read the MSDN article for the struct for details.

Comment: @HansPassant, you are right. I am add `menuitem.fMask = MIIM_TYPE | MIIM_DATA;` and it works well. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using Ansi functions? Windows has supported Unicode as standard for nearly 20 years.

Comment: Not checking for errors never helps. Always check for errors.

Answer (score 7):

As @HansPassant pointed out the solution is:

> You are not using MENUITEMDATA correctly, you forgot to set the fMask member. Read the MSDN article for the struct for details

and then:

> add `menuitem.fMask = MIIM_TYPE | MIIM_DATA;` and it works well

I can't take credit for this solution but am providing it here so that the next person that needs an answer to that question can easily find it without parsing the comments' section